# My native language special characters don't work on LaTeX

Tags: latex

I'm new to LaTeX and I'm trying to make my Cover Letter on Overleaf. My name is Codruț Ștefan, and when I want to implement that in this section, the "ț" and the "Ș" don't render:

```
\namesection{Codrut Stefan}{Ursache}{ 
\href{mailto:ursache.codrut71@gmail.com}{ursache.codrut71@gmail.com} | 0765991609 | 
\urlstyle{same}\href{https://github.com/Kreker71}{Github} | 
\urlstyle{same}\href{https://www.facebook.com/ursache.codrut}{Facebook}
}
```

The strange part is that when I write these special characters in the main part of the letter, everything is all right.
I also included these special tags at the begging `\usepackage[romanian]{babel} \usepackage{combelow}`

Please help me and sorry if it's a dumb question.
[image]

cover.tex:

```
 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Deedy - Cover Letter Template
% LaTeX Template
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%



\documentclass[]{cover}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
 
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
 
\rfoot{Page \thepage \hspace{1pt}}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%     TITLE NAME
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\namesection{Codruț Ștefan}{Ursache}{ \href{mailto:ursache.codrut71@gmail.com}{ursache.codrut71@gmail.com} | 0765991609 | \urlstyle{same}\href{https://github.com/Kreker71}{Github} | \urlstyle{same}\href{https://www.facebook.com/ursache.codrut}{Facebook}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%     MAIN COVER LETTER CONTENT
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\hfill

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth} 
\companyname{Microsoft Learn Student Ambassadors}

\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\textwidth} 
\currentdate{\today}
\end{minipage}

\vspace*{7mm}

\lettercontent{\hspace*{10mm} Dragă recrutant,}

% The first paragraph of your job application letter should include information on why you are writing. Mention the job you are applying for and where you found the position. If you have a contact at the company, mention the person's name and your connection here.

\lettercontent{\hspace*{10mm} Numele meu este Ursache Codruț-Ștefan. Am 18 ani și în prezent sunt student la Universitatea Politehnica din București, pe profilul Calculatoare și Tehnologia Informației. Atracția mea către domeniul informaticii a început din copilărie, prin prisma jocurilor pe calculator, ce reprezentau o provocare pentru mine, de a înțelege conceptele tehnice din spatele funcționalității acestora. Cu timpul, informatica a devenit o pasiune, fapt ce m-a determinat să urmez un profil de Matematică și Informatică cu predarea intensivă a Informaticii la Colegiul Național B.P.Hasdeu din Buzău, fiind unul dintre cele mai prestigioase licee din țară. Datorită metodelor avansate de predare, am putut să îmi însușesc un nivel de cunoștințe generale ridicat, cât și o bază complexă în primul meu limbaj de programare studiat, și anume C++.
}


   
% The next section of your cover letter should describe what you have to offer the company. Make strong connections between your abilities and the requirements listed in the job posting. Mention specifically how your skills and experience match the job. Expand on the information in your resume.
% Try to support each statement you make with a piece of evidence. Use several shorter paragraphs or bullets rather than one large block of text, which can be difficult to read and absorb quickly.
%For example 

% Using the knowledge and skills I have acquired in my <DEGREE PROGRAM> combined with my technical abilities I believe I can provide significant value to <COMPANY> while providing me invaluable experience to <PREPARE FOR OR FURTHER CAREER>.
% <RELEVANT LIFE STORY/ WORK/ PROJECT >
% In own projects, my coursework, work as a <PREVIOUS JOB TITLE> I have applied knowledge of <SUBJECT MATTER>.
% <LIST OF SMART SOUNDING SKILLS AND TOOLS>.
% Combining these tools with my interests in <FIELD> issues, I hope to help the <DEPARTMENT> answer questions about the <SUBJECT> behind <FIELD> projects.

\lettercontent{\hspace*{10mm}Lumea se află în prezent într-o eră dominată de avansul rapid al tehnologiei asupra oamenilor, prin infiltrațiile sale în domenii cum ar fi medicina, inginerie, business. Fiind o fire cu o voință puternică cu privire la procesele de auto-învățare, pe care le consider esențiale în etapele pe care le parcurge un viitor programator, atenția mea a fost concentrată pe toate noutățile apărute din sfera științei, pentru a putea înțelege mai bine ce rol are și va avea în viitor tehnologia în viețile noastre. Acest lucru m-a determinat să înțeleg mai bine necesitățile lumii moderne, în strânsa legătura cu lumile artificiale create de fiecare calculator în parte.
}

%Proiect personal

\lettercontent{\hspace*{10mm}În clasa a 11-a, prin suportul imens acordat din partea unui profesor de informatică din cadrul liceului, am reușit să realizez primul meu proiect, ce a constat într-o oglindă inteligentă, ce îmbină eficient componente hardware, cum ar fi o placă principală de tip RaspberryPy Model 3B, și programare software, folosind concepte de Linux, NodeJS și Python. Dimensiunile acesteia sunt moderate, astfel încât se pot integra zone în care utilizatorul poate accesa știrile zilei, vremea, moduri diferite de vizualizare ce modifică luminozitatea, contrastul imaginii etc, în funcție de momentul în care oglinda este folosită. De asemenea, în funcție de momentul zilei, aceasta afișează un mesaj motivațional diferit(ex.: Dimineața între orele 07-10am sunt prezentate mesaje specifice pentru dimineață, precum "Bună dimineața!", "Cum a fost somnul?", "Gata pentru o nouă zi?"). Utilizarea site-ului GitHub m-a făcut să realizez cât de strânsă și unită este comunitatea de programatori din întreaga lume, prin intermediul acestuia reușind să implementez o funcție de RemoteControl a oglinzii prin intermediul smartphone-ului(widget-urile și oglinda pot fi închise și deschise de pe telefon).
}

% Proiecte liceu

\lettercontent{\hspace*{10mm}În perioada liceului, am înțeles cât de important este să pătrund cât mai adânc în diferite domenii ce fac parte din întregul științei calculatoarelor. O parte din efortul meu academic era îndreptat către rezolvarea problemelor de programare, fie ele strict efectuate în timpul orelor, fie proiecte avansate, cum ar fi jocuri sau aplicații. În timpul unui opțional în clasa a 11-a, am parcurs elemente de C\#, reușind, în decurs de doar câteva săptămâni, să proiectez diferite aplicații practice, destinate înțelegerii mai limpede a modului în care operează C\#, prin aceste procese educaționale: convertor valutar, tabel periodic al elementelor digital, generarea unor fractali și un calculator matematic. Lucrând la aceste aplicații, cât și la programe ce presupuneau o diversitate de noțiuni matematice, am conștientizat relația de interdependență dintre cele două ramuri științifice, matematica fiind un alt domeniu pe care mi-am canalizat atenția.}

%
% PATH
%

\lettercontent{\hspace*{10mm} Întotdeauna am fost adeptul ideii de posibilă conviețuire cu un calculator capabil să funcționeze autonom. Domeniul inteligenței artificiale cu ale sale sub-ramuri, Machine Learning și Deep Learning, creează pretextul unui viitor în care relațiile inter-umane vor fi dominate de legăturile stabilite între oameni și calculatoare. Fiind o persoană capabilă să se adapteze la orice provocare apărută în cadrul științei, cu precădere a științei calculatoarelor, fac parte din comunitatea ce se află în continuă dezvoltare, a oamenilor implicați, activ sau pasiv, în cercetarea inteligenței artificiale, aflată încă într-un stadiu de plină expansiune. De aceea, îmi doresc să fiu îndrumat corespunzător de către Microsoft Learn Student Ambassadors, spre a aprofunda noțiunile unei viitoare cariere de succes, combinând cercetarea acestui domeniu, până la realizarea programelor capabile să se auto-cerceteze.}

\lettercontent{\hspace*{10mm} Când vine vorba de hobby-uri, îmi place să mă surprind și să încerc lucruri noi, însă principalele mele atracții sunt îndreptate către fotografie și cinematografie. Fiecare fotografie ascunde în spatele ei o poveste ce poate fi descoperită la o analiză mai amănunțită, pixelii conținând nu doar o combinație de valori RGB, ci și o emoție sau o trăire a fotografului sau a obiectului fotografiat. Ceea ce ador cel mai mult la fotografie nu este acțiunea propriu-zisă de a face poze, ci posibilitatea de a o îmbina cu alte pasiuni dragi mie, cum ar fi drumețiile, concertele și observatul stelelor. Pe de altă parte, mă consider un cinefil dedicat. Părerea mea este că la fel cum elevii trebuie să învețe literatură și despre cât de multe lucruri are de oferit și de ascuns o carte, ar trebui să existe o oră asemănătoare pentru studiul filmelor, în care elevul are șansa să descopere de ce o anumită scenă a fost filmată cu cadre foarte mari, de ce filmul a fost produs Alb-Negru deși tehnologia din momentul filmării permitea o imagine color sau în câte moduri poate fi interpretat un anumit final. Trăim într-o eră a audio-vizualului în care, din păcate, din ce în ce mai multe filme care "au ceva de spus" sunt umbrite de filme comerciale, de cinema, pline de efecte speciale și lipsite de mesaj sau poveste.}

\lettercontent{\hspace*{10mm} Din punct de vedere al laturii sociale, sunt o persoană ce asociază fiecare interacțiune cu oamenii ca fiind o experiență din care pot învăța lucruri noi, ce mă pot ajuta în procesul meu de dezvoltare personală. De altfel, simt o nevoie intensă de a fi implicat în acte de voluntariat, dorind să am o contribuție, oricât de mică, asupra acțiunilor de ajutorare a oamenilor, dar și a animalelor. De exemplu, în primul an de liceu, am fost organizator într-o echipă ce a desfășurat un carnaval cu tematica Harry Potter, unde se vindeau sucuri și prăjituri. Banii strânși de pe urma acestora, cât și de pe urma vânzării biletelor pentru a putea intra la carnaval au fost donați unei case de bătrâni din orașul în care locuiesc.
}

\lettercontent{}

\lettercontent{}

\vspace{0.5cm}

\signature{Ursache Codruț Ștefan}

\end{document}  
\documentclass[]{article}
```

cover.cls:

```
% Intro Options
\ProvidesClass{deedy-resume-openfont}[2014/04/30 CV class]
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\DeclareOption{print}{\def\@cv@print{}}
\DeclareOption*{%
  \PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}
}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass{article}

% Package Imports
\usepackage[hmargin=2.54cm, vmargin=2.54cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}

% Publications
\usepackage{cite}
\renewcommand\refname{\vskip -1.5cm}

% Color definitions
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor} 
\definecolor{date}{HTML}{666666} 
\definecolor{primary}{HTML}{2b2b2b} 
\definecolor{headings}{HTML}{6A6A6A}
\definecolor{subheadings}{HTML}{333333}

% Set main fonts
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Color=primary, Path = OpenFonts/fonts/lato/,BoldItalicFont=Lato-RegIta,BoldFont=Lato-Reg,ItalicFont=Lato-LigIta]{Lato-Lig}
\setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text, Path = OpenFonts/fonts/raleway/]{Raleway-ExtraLight}

% Date command
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
% \usepackage[UKenglish]{isodate}
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1mm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1mm}
\newcommand{\lastupdated}{\begin{textblock}{60}(155,5)
\color{date}\fontspec[Path = OpenFonts/fonts/raleway/]{Raleway-ExtraLight}\fontsize{8pt}{10pt}\selectfont 
Last Updated on \today
\end{textblock}}

% Name command
\newcommand{\namesection}[3]{
\centering{
\fontsize{40pt}{60pt}
\fontspec[Path = OpenFonts/fonts/lato/]{Lato-Hai}\selectfont #1 
\fontspec[Path = OpenFonts/fonts/lato/]{Lato-Lig}\selectfont #2
} \\[5pt]
\centering{
\color{headings}
\fontspec[Path = OpenFonts/fonts/raleway/]{Raleway-Medium}\fontsize{11pt}{14pt}\selectfont #3}
\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\color{headings}\rule{\paperwidth}{0.0pt}}
\vspace{0pt}
}

% Section seperators 
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt} 
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\newcommand{\sectionsep}{\vspace{8pt}}

% Headings command
\titleformat{\section}{\color{headings}
\scshape\fontspec[Path = OpenFonts/fonts/OpenFonts/fonts/lato/]{Lato-Lig}\fontsize{16pt}{24pt}\selectfont \raggedright\uppercase}{}{0em}{}

% Subeadings command
\titleformat{\subsection}{
\color{subheadings}\fontspec[Path = OpenFonts/fonts/lato/]{Lato-Bol}\fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont\bfseries\uppercase}{}{0em}{}

\newcommand{\runsubsection}[1]{
\color{subheadings}\fontspec[Path = OpenFonts/fonts/lato/]{Lato-Bol}\fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont\bfseries\uppercase {#1} \normalfont}

% Descriptors command
\newcommand{\descript}[1]{
\color{subheadings}\raggedright\scshape\fontspec[Path = OpenFonts/fonts/raleway/]{Raleway-Medium}\fontsize{11pt}{13pt}\selectfont {#1 \\} \normalfont}

% Location command
\newcommand{\location}[1]{
\color{headings}\raggedright\fontspec[Path = OpenFonts/fonts/raleway/]{Raleway-Medium}\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont {#1\\} \normalfont}

% Bullet Lists with fewer gaps command
\newenvironment{tightemize}{
\vspace{-\topsep}\begin{itemize}\itemsep1pt \parskip0pt \parsep0pt}
{\end{itemize}\vspace{-\topsep}}

% Cover Letter
\newcommand{\companyname}[1]{\raggedright\fontspec[Path = OpenFonts/fonts/lato/]{Lato-Bol}\fontsize{12pt}{14pt}\selectfont {#1 \\} \normalfont}

\newcommand{\companyaddress}[1]{\raggedright\fontspec[Path = OpenFonts/fonts/raleway/]{Raleway-Medium}\fontsize{11pt}{13pt}\selectfont {#1 \\}\mbox{}\\\mbox{}\\ \normalfont}

\newcommand{\currentdate}[1]{\raggedleft\fontspec[Path = OpenFonts/fonts/raleway/]{Raleway-Medium}\fontsize{11pt}{13pt}\selectfont {#1 \\} \normalfont}

% Letter content command
\newcommand{\lettercontent}[1]{\raggedright\fontspec[Path = OpenFonts/fonts/raleway/]{Raleway-Medium}\fontsize{11pt}{13pt}\selectfont {#1 \\}\mbox{}\\ \normalfont}

\newcommand{\closing}[1]{\raggedright\fontspec[Path = OpenFonts/fonts/raleway/]{Raleway-Medium}\fontsize{11pt}{13pt}\selectfont {#1 \\}\mbox{}\\\mbox{}\\ \normalfont}

\newcommand{\signature}[1]{\raggedright\fontspec[Path = OpenFonts/fonts/raleway/]{Raleway-Medium}\fontsize{11pt}{13pt}\selectfont {#1 \\} \normalfont}
```

Comment: Please share the whole preamble (everything before `\begin{document}`). Did you specify utf8 and the T1 font encoding? A [mcve] would help. Finally, try a different font, maybe the target font doesn't have these characters?

Comment: @Robert utf8 is default since a couple of years. Even overleaf now uses a distribution new enough...

Comment: @Codrut We really need a [mre] for this. Without seeing the code it is impossible to guess

Comment: How can I change the font?

Comment: @CodrutUrsache, why don't you try on [TeX & LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/)? I used to post LaTeX questions there, and they are extremely responsive.

Comment: I second Robert suspicion about a font idea. It works fine with font that have these special characters, e.g. `Arial`

Comment: Thanks a lot! One more noob question: How can I change the font? :D

Comment: Look in the cover.cls file for the lines with `\fontspec` and `\setmainfont`/`\setsansfont`

Comment: For example `% Name command
\newcommand{\namesection}[3]{
\centering{
\fontsize{40pt}{60pt}
\fontspec[]{Arial}\selectfont #1 
\fontspec[]{Arial}\selectfont #2
} \\[5pt]
\centering{
\color{headings}
\fontspec[]{Arial}\fontsize{11pt}{14pt}\selectfont #3}
\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\color{headings}\rule{\paperwidth}{0.0pt}}
\vspace{0pt}
}`

Comment: (There are probably fonts that will better match the design of the document then Arial, but I don't know which fonts you have available )

Comment: Now I've changed the font to Arial and it's the same issue

Comment: Update: It worked after I used \c{t} and \c{S} for the special characters

Comment: [**Related thread on Tex SE**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/260651/romanian-language-in-latex)